# How Auto start apps are able to start after reboot?

Tags: applications, xiaomi, oneplus-5t

Many OEMs have restrictions which do not allow an application to run after boot complete. For this, we need to give autostart permission to that app. Then how does apps like Autostart, startup manager are able to run right after boot without having any permissions? Autostart is developed by a small team and is not as popular as whatsapp, facebook and others that it can be whitelisted by the OEM. Any inputs will be helpful.

Edit1: I am aware of broadcast receiver but even after using them user needs to manually set autostart permission for my application to be able to run the application in background after BOOT_COMPLETE. However this is not the case for autostart apps.

Thanks.

Comment: When talking about a specific app please always include a link to the PlayStore web page of that app, because there are a lot of "Autostart" apps available and it is not quite clear which one you are referring to. There are different events that come frequently (e.g. BatteryLevel*) so that you don't need BOOT_COMPLETE if you want to start something some short time after boot.

Comment: How do you know Autostart app runs right after boot?

Comment: @Robert https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.autostart&hl=en&gl=US this is the link of one such app. I read on Google's developer page [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions) that apps can now listen to only a few implicit intents.